# Problem in understanding datetime difference and invert

Tags: php, datetime

I am having a problem in understanding the difference between datetime. I am using PHP datetime class.

Here is a small part of my code to calculate the datetime difference:

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");

function timeline_date($date)
{
    $today = new DateTime();
    $timeline_date = new DateTime($date);
    $interval = $today->diff($timeline_date);

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($today);
    print_r($timeline_date);
    print_r($interval);
    echo "</pre>";
}
$date = "2019-02-02 04:36:02";
echo timeline_date($date);
```

What is the meaning of statement:

```
$interval = $today->diff($timeline_date);
```

Is it subtracting $timeline_date from $today?

Or is it subtracting $today from $timeline_date?

I am having a great confusion regarding this particular statement. I searched on Internet but nothing is clearly mentioned on it.

Also $timeline_date can be past or future date and even today's date. So does it matter we should subtract small quantity from large quantity?

I get following output from above code:

```
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2019-02-05 16:11:37
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => Asia/Kolkata
)
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2019-02-02 04:36:02
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => Asia/Kolkata
)
DateInterval Object
(
    [y] => 0
    [m] => 0
    [d] => 3
    [h] => 11
    [i] => 35
    [s] => 35
    [weekday] => 0
    [weekday_behavior] => 0
    [first_last_day_of] => 0
    [invert] => 1
    [days] => 3
    [special_type] => 0
    [special_amount] => 0
    [have_weekday_relative] => 0
    [have_special_relative] => 0
)
```

We can see `[invert] => 1` in above array. What is actual meaning of it? If I change the $date to:

```
$date = "2019-02-10 04:36:02";
```

Then `[invert] => 0` changes to 1. Why? Does it mean if we have past date in difference then invert will be 0 and if we have future date then this array element will be 1?

Comment: see the docs: invert
Is 1 if the interval represents a negative time period and 0 otherwise. See DateInterval::format().

Comment: *$interval = $today->diff($timeline_date);* gets the DateInterval from today. Invert is 1 if the provided date was before today or 0 if it is in future for today

Comment: @ViktarPryshchepa In your first comment, what do you mean by negative time period? Can you explain the term with an example?

Comment: I have taken this line from the docs. This means that you passed to diff method the datetime which occurred before the date you call method on

Comment: @ViktarPryshchepa okay so it sounds like past date.

Comment: Example: `'2019-02-10'->diff('2019-02-08')` as a result invert would be 1
and for `'2019-02-10'->diff('2019-02-11')` invert would be 0

Comment: @ViktarPryshchepa fair clear now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DateTime::diff` gives you the *difference* between the two dates, somewhat obviously. It doesn't really matter which one is bigger or smaller, a delta is a delta regardless of that. However, the resulting `DateInterval` object *does* note which one was bigger or smaller with the [`DateInterval::$invert`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php#dateinterval.props.invert) property:

> Is *1* if the interval represents a negative time period and *0* otherwise. See [`DateInterval::format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php).

The rule is if `$b` in `$a->diff($b)` is before `$a`, `$invert` is `1`. Looking at said `DateInterval::format`, you'll see:

> *`R`*    Sign "-" when negative, "+" when positive
>   *`r`*    Sign "-" when negative, empty when positive

So, if you *do* care about the future/past difference, you can use the `%R`/`%r` formatting parameters in `DateInterval::format` to output a "-" and/or "+". If you don't care, just omit that option and it's irrelevant.